# Woocommerce cart total not showing extra fees added by add_fee()

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to unset a payment method if the cart total meets some criteria. So wrote the code in `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees hook` for checking the cart total and unset the payment method.

I have tried the functions,

`WC()->cart->cart_contents_total`

and

```
floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) )
```

to get the cart total.

But these methods are returning cart total without considering the extra fees that I added to the cart using the function `add_fee()` on the hook `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways`

So is there any way to

> get cart total including the extra fees inside the
>   woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees hook

OR

> Can I unset one of my payment method inside
>   woocommerce_available_payment_gateways hook

Thanks

Comment: Are you writing an event handler in your functions.php or are you trying to edit WooCommerce directly? I would not recommend the latter as it is the incorrect way of doing it. If you are doing it the former way then the problem is likely the execution order. Can you please show a snippet of how you are using the woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the fees using `WC()->cart->get_fees()`

```
$cartFess =  WC()->cart->get_fees();
$cFees = 0;
foreach($cartFess as $cfee){
    $cFees = $cFees + $cfee->amount ;
}
$cartTotal = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total + $cFees;
```